# Android 4.3 Hiding Navigation Bar for UDOO project

Tags: android, navigationbar

I've been developing an application on Android for UDOO which has to run as car mode. (I don't use kiosk mode because if user type the right password application has to end and return to launcher.)

My application runs on Android 4.1 perfectly but UDOO has Android 4.3 and it doesn't work right. Is there any option that refers to car mode on Android 4.3?

The other solution that I've found is hiding the navigation bar. But Android 4.3 doesn't allow to do that.

Is there a solution for that problem on 4.3 or what can you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code to hide title bar :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

Add your theme name instead of 'Light'

Comment: I tried this one already. But it's not doing what i want. Thanks anyway.